# C# Asyn. Socket Programming

Tags: .net, asp.net, unit-testing, sockets

Is it possible to unit test the Asyn. socket programming (using c#)?  Provide some sample unit test code.

Comment: @user919426 You claim that the answer is "old" and you point at Microsoft documentation which uses Socket instead of Stream. However, these are just different abstractions. You can wrap a Socket in a NetworkStream to turn it into a stream. The documentation for socket also suggests to use TCPClient instead, which gives you a Stream. If there's something old about my answer below, it would be the usage of BeginWrite/EndWrite instead of the more modern WriteAsync.

Comment: Hi @WimCoenen.. Please take no offense. Old in the sense that `APM` is no longer the recommended pattern for asynchronous TCP. Instead `async/await` is now recommended ( https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/4828#issuecomment-643694377 ). The Microsoft documentation is outdated and based on that older APM pattern.  I have my answer. The bounty is no longer of use.

Answer (score 9):

I assume you are testing some class of your own that uses .NET streams; let's call it `MessageSender`. Note that there is no reason to unit test the .NET streams themselves, that's Microsoft's job. You should not unit test .NET framework code, just your own.

First, make sure that you **inject** the stream used by `MessageSender`. Don't create it inside the class but accept it as a property value or constructor argument. For example:

```
public sealed class MessageSender
{
   private readonly Stream stream;

   public MessageSender(Stream stream)
   {
      if (stream == null)
         throw new ArgumentNullException("stream");
      this.stream = stream;
   }

   public IAsyncResult BeginSendHello(AsyncCallback callback, object state)
   {
      byte[] message = new byte[] {0x01, 0x02, 0x03};
      return this.stream.BeginWrite(
         message, 0, message.Length, callback, state);
   }

   public void EndSendHello(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   {
      this.stream.EndWrite(asyncResult);
   }
}
```

Now an example test: you could test that `BeginSendHello` invokes `BeginWrite` on the stream, and sends the correct bytes. We'll mock the stream and set up an expectation to verify this. I'm using the [RhinoMocks](http://ayende.com/projects/rhino-mocks.aspx) framework in this example.

```
[Test]
public void BeginSendHelloInvokesBeginWriteWithCorrectBytes()
{
   var mocks = new MockRepository();
   var stream = mocks.StrictMock<Stream>();
   Expect.Call(stream.BeginWrite(
      new byte[] {0x01, 0x02, 0x03}, 0, 3, null, null));
   mocks.ReplayAll();

   var messageSender = new MessageSender(stream);
   messageSender.BeginSendHello(null, null);

   mocks.VerifyAll();
}
```